# Derivative of a special function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the following formula, what is the derivative with respect to x?

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x^Ty_i}$$

Comment: Is $x$ not a column vector in that equation? If not, what does the superscript $T$ represent if not the transpose of a vector? And if it is a vector, what do you mean by partial derivative wrt it? Perhaps you mean gradient?

Comment: for example x = (1, 2) and y_i is a vector with length 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use linearity of differentiation and the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{i=1}^ny_{ij}e^{x^Ty_i}$$
so
$$\nabla f=\sum_{i=1}^ny_ie^{x^Ty_i}.$$